# K-means algorithm in python getting runtime error

Tags: python, k-means

I'm implementing k-means as follows:

```
def labels(mean_0, mean_1, Xtrain): # assign classes according to given mean
    labels =[]
    for row in Xtrain:
        dist1 = np.linalg.norm(row-mean_0)
        dist2 = np.linalg.norm(row-mean_1)
        if dist1>= dist2:
            labels.append(1)
        else:
            labels.append(0)
    return labels        
            
def data_for_class(labels, data):  #find the examples for each class
    #class1_indices = np.nonzero(np.array(labels))
    
    labels = np.array(labels)
    class1_indices = np.where(labels == 1)[0]
    class0_indices = np.where(labels == 0)[0]
    class1_list = [data[i] for i in class1_indices]
    class0_list = [data[i] for i in class0_indices]
    return class0_list, class1_list
mean_0 = np.zeros(7)
mean_1 = 10 * np.ones(7)
while True:
    # now get the labels for original dataset
    mean0_pre = mean_0
    mean1_pre = mean_1
    y_pre = labels(mean0_pre, mean1_pre, Tr_normalized)
    # seperate data and recalculate mean
    [class0_data, class1_data] = data_for_class(y_pre, Tr_normalized)
    mean0_new = np.mean(class0_data, axis=0)
    mean1_new = np.mean(class1_data, axis=0)
    y_new = labels(mean0_new, mean1_new, Tr_normalized)
    change0 = np.linalg.norm(mean0_new - mean0_pre)
    change1 = np.linalg.norm(mean1_new - mean1_pre)
    mean0_pre = mean0_new
    mean1_pre = mean1_new
    if change0 <= 10 and change1 <= 10 :
        break
```

I feel like everything should be working but I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\azara\Anaconda3\Ano\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:3334: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
C:\Users\azara\Anaconda3\Ano\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:161: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
```

Can someone help me with this? I don't get what's goin on! I'm new to python

Comment: Can you please provide the *complete* traceback, as well as modifying your code into a [mcve]?